# Haskell GHCi won't start

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I installed the ghc and now I try to run ghci. However, when I type in "ghci" in the command line, I get:

> /usr/local/bin/ghc-7.10.2: line 9: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.10.2/bin/ghc:Success

What does that mean? How to "repair" it?

Comment: Where did you install it from; which instructions did you use? GHC 7.10.2 is more than 6 years old. I would suggest trying to remove what you have installed and then using [ghcup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) to install GHC 8.10.7.

Comment: I need to work on an old project, where only this ghc version is compatible

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_2.html this is where I downloaded the ghc

Comment: Oh, in that case I can't help much. If nobody else answers then you could still try to install GHC 7.10.3 with ghcup, that should still be compatible with your project.